# Error: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

Tags: python, regression

I am solving a random forest  regression  problem. code is below

```
import pandas as pd 
dataset =pd.read_csv ('C:/random forest/data.csv', decimal=',')
xrf1 = dataset.iloc[:,0:3].values
RESULTS_FOLDER='C:/random forest'
model_path = os.path.join(RESULTS_FOLDER, 'modele rf1.pkl')
model = joblib.load(model_path)
predrf1 = model.predict(xrf1)
```

I am getting an error

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
> dtype('float32').

Here you find the link of my data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nuajvw0xuux7bm3/data.csv?dl=0

Please help me solve this error please .

Comment: something wrong with reading in the csv. One of your columns is a string instead of float, you need to use `decimal=","`

Comment: When posting questions, please post *full* stack trace. not just the error.

Comment: Also provide data along with questions or they won't be reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your number contains a comma, that Python does not understand. You can verify this by typing `float('-12,95525169')`, and you'll get the same error.

However, since you are using pandas, you can maybe solve this pretty easily.

If all your floats have the same comma separator, you can use the following to read your CSV file:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:/random forest/data.csv", delimiter=";", decimal=",")
```

Adding the `decimal=","` parameter, pandas will parse the string and convert it to float properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your string has a comma in it. Python’s formatting (and thus it’s parser) uses the period as decimal separator and does not have thousands separators.